# Make a rails query more efficient

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to make this more efficient. Is there a better approach for this or a way to create an sql statement out of this?

```
def current_week_correct_picks
   @model.picks.select do |p| 
      p.picked_team == p.match.winning_team && p.match.date.in?(current_week)
   end.count
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave your calculations completely on the database. Something like this should work:

```rb
@model
  .picks
  .joins(:match)
  .where('picks.picked_team = matches.winning_team')
  .where(matches: { date: current_week })
  .count
```

Notes:

- My assumption is `picks` are association to `@model` they have their own database table and model.
- Another assumption is that every `pick` has maximum of one `match`. If not, use `.count('distinct picks.id')` instead of just `.count`, so you accidentally don't count some picks more than once.
- In the where clauses you have to use DB table names, not model names

Comment: Why not to include `:picks` while querying?

Comment: @Imran he is querying `picks` directly, there is no need to include them explicitly, at least that is mine assumption. If you do just `@model.picks.count`, following SQL query will be produced: `SELECT count(*) FROM picks WHERE picks.model_id=123`

Comment: I asked because @David is iterating through picks.

Comment: @Imran That is true, but @David is doing `count` at the end. So if I understood it correctly, he is iterating through the picks only because he needs to filter them to get final count of correct picks. In my answer all of this job is done directly by database. It is much faster and he doesn't go through all of the picks again in the Ruby.